# Getting a list of active characters

Tags: catcodes, active-characters, mathcode

There are some characters that are active in plain TeX (e.g. `~`) and some packages like `babel` make additional characters active (e.g. `"`). Is there a way to get a list of all active characters from within TeX? Alternatively, is there a reference listing which characters are made active by common packages?

A similar list of characters with `\mathcode` `"8000` would be nice as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all characters, testing the catcode of every one of them. Then just print the active/mathactive(`\mathcode="8000`) ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\currentchar
\currentchar=0
\loop
  \ifnum\active=\catcode\currentchar
    Character code \number\currentchar, aka ``\texttt{\char\currentchar}'', is active. It's meaning is:\\
    \texttt{%
      \lccode`\~=\currentchar\lowercase{\meaning~}
    }.\par
  \else
    \ifnum"8000=\mathcode\currentchar
      Character code \number\currentchar, aka ``\texttt{\char\currentchar}'', is mathactive. It's meaning is:\\
      \texttt{%
        \lccode`\~=\currentchar\lowercase{\meaning~}
      }.\par
    \fi
  \fi
  \advance \currentchar by 1
  \ifnum\currentchar<256
\repeat
\end{document}
```

This also tries to output the character (Of course this only works if there is a printable character in that position) and the definition.
You will find that there are lots of active characters, mostly coming from `inputenc`.

The most interesting part of the output probably is:
[image]

For Unicode engines like XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, you have to replace `256` by `"110000` (the number of Unicode codepoints) and `"8000` by `"1000000`. So you get

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\currentchar
\currentchar=0
\loop
  \ifnum\active=\catcode\currentchar
    Character code \number\currentchar, aka ``\texttt{\char\currentchar}'', is active. It's meaning is:\\
    \texttt{%
      \lccode`\~=\currentchar\lowercase{\meaning~}
    }.\par
  \else
    \ifnum"1000000=\mathcode\currentchar
      Character code \number\currentchar, aka ``\texttt{\char\currentchar}'', is mathactive. It's meaning is:\\
      \texttt{%
        \lccode`\~=\currentchar\lowercase{\meaning~}
      }.\par
    \fi
  \fi
  \advance \currentchar by 1
  \ifnum\currentchar<"110000
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Here, `inputenc` is not needed, so you only get what you expect (This is LuaLaTeX, for XeTeX `\mathcode` works slightly different):
[image]

Comment: The second code is fine with LuaTeX, but it does not work with XeTeX.